# 7x3 dataset - How do you create unique sets in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Here's my [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_foBvmJZrNCOSIrvH-Tkbz6hqanTf_DQu8RMc9Nsum8/edit#gid=0)

B3:D9 is a simplified dataset. I need a formula to create the unique sets in F3:H6.

**Sample Data**

| B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Rock | Green-1036 |  |
| Paper | Red-994 |  |
| Rock |  | Brown-781 |
| Scissors |  | Yellow-1271 |
| Paper |  | Blue-2211 |
| Scissors | Purple-546 |  |
| Shoot | Orange |  |

**Desired Output**

| F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Rock | Green-1036 | Brown-781 |
| Paper | Red-994 | Blue-2211 |
| Scissors | Purple-546 | Yellow-1271 |
| Shoot | Orange |  |

I had a similar question last year that was answered on the "Previous StackEx Support" tab in case it helps. The lambda solution was great. I tried to modify it by removing the Sort and Textjoin but I'm not very familiar with the lambda function and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: This doesn't look like a practical, detailed question about using Google Sheets. While including a link to an external resource might be helpful, posts on this site should be self contained. Please describe the relevant parts of your spreadsheet, add the sample input data and the expected output as text directly into the question body. Show what you have tried. Please bear in mind that question on this site should not include chit chat, (i.e. "Thanks so much!").

Comment: @Rubén-PeopleFirst thank you. I added the data directly into the question body, added more detail, and removed the chit chat.

Answer (score 0):

Use `let()`, `lambda()`, `choosecols()`, `unique()`, `filter()`, `iferror()`, `vlookup()` and `bycol()`, along these lines:

```
=let( 
  data, B3:D, 
  first, choosecols(data, 1), 
  keys, unique(first), 
  filter_, lambda(d, filter({ first, d }, len(d))), 
  lookup_, lambda(d, 
    arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(keys, filter_(d), 2, false))) 
  ), 
  bycol(data, lookup_) 
)
```

See
[let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535),
[lambda()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718),
[choosecols()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13197914),
[unique()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093198),
[filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197),
[iferror()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093304),
[vlookup()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093318)
and
[bycol()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12571032).

Answer (score 0):

#### Formula

This version **includes** any values in column B that have no associated value in column C or column D *(see image below)*

```
=LET(arr,{B:C;B:B,D:D},
  a,INDEX(arr,,1), b,INDEX(arr,,2), 
  BYROW(TOCOL(UNIQUE(a),1), LAMBDA(u,
    TOROW({u;FILTER(b,a=u)},1))))
```

**<sub>Includes Col B Values even if  Col C and D empty</sub>**[image]

#### Variation

This variation **excludes** any values in column B that have no associated value in column C or column D *(see image below)*

```
=LET(arr,{B:C;B:B,D:D},
  a,INDEX(arr,,1), b,INDEX(arr,,2), 
  BYROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(a,LEN(b)),
    LAMBDA(u, TOROW(
      {u;FILTER(b,a=u)},1))))
```

**<sub>Excludes Col B Values even if  Col C and D empty</sub>**[image]